# Toggle css is not working in Internet explorer

Tags: html, css

I have created a custom toggle with checkbox and its is working fine in chrome but not working in IE 11. How to fix that issue ?

this is my css I have checked in IE ,is that Webkit appearance not supported?

```css
    body{
        text-align: center;
    }
    
    input[type="checkbox"]{
        position: relative;
        width: 60px;
        height: 30px;
        -webkit-appearance: none;
        appearance: none;
        -moz-appearance: none;
        background:#d6d6d6;
        border-radius: 20px;
        outline:none;
    }
    input[type="checkbox"]::-ms-expand{
        display: none;
    }
    input:checked[type='checkbox']{
        background:#0196fe;
    
    }
    input[type="checkbox"]:before{
        content: '';
        position:absolute;
        width: 30px;
        height: 30px;
        border-radius: 50%;
        background: white;
        border: 2px solid #000000;
        left: 0;
        top:-1px;
    }
    input:checked[type="checkbox"]:before{
        left: 30px;
        border: 2px solid #5dc8f1;
    }
```

```html
    <Input type="checkbox" name="checkbox" />
```

Answer (score 4):

Replace

```
input[type="checkbox"]::-ms-expand {
    display: none;
}
```

with

```
input[type="checkbox"]::-ms-check {
    visibility: hidden;
    /* or */
    opacity: 0;
}
```

[`-ms-expand`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/::-ms-expand) is for select elements whereas [`-ms-check`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/::-ms-check) targets checkboxes and radiobuttons.

Comment: can we remove -ms-check? is any other way to fix the issue

Comment: I absolutely agree this ! Hope that it'll resolve his issue

Comment: Oh you probably need to just make it invisible rather than `display: none`. I've edited my answer.